# must load import bpy on all scripts, not just __init__?

Tags: scripting, add-on

So - I'm creating a zip package to be installed as an add-on. I refactored my code so that classes with operators are in several separate .py scripts, while my view panels are right in the **init** file. I have import bpy at the top of my init file. But when I try to activate the add-on, i get a "NameError: name 'bpy' is not defined".

I can fix this if I put an import bpy at the top of every script file. My add-on is now working.

But why would this be necessary? Why not just import bpy on the top of the init file and then boom good to go?

Comment: To my understanding, imports in `_init_` load the module, while the same imports in your submodules actually just tell that submodule that the modules names refers to the already loaded modules. [Understanding Python imports, \_\_init\_\_.py and pythonpath — once and for all | by Dr. Varshita Sher | Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-python-imports-init-py-and-pythonpath-once-and-for-all-4c5249ab6355)